# Neighborhoods issues in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis

1. Let  ɛ > 0 and δ  > 0, and a∈  R. Show that Vɛ(a)∩Vδ(a) and Vɛ (a) ∪Vδ (a) are  γ -neighbor-
   hoods of a for appropriate values of γ.
2. Show that if a, b∈  R, and a ≠ b, then there exist ɛ-neighborhoods U of a and V of b such that 
   U ∩ V =ϕ

Comment: General hint: as you are in a metric space, **you have to work with balls**. For the second property, it deals with separateness axiom with the same $\epsilon$ for the two neighborhoods.

Comment: Is "Vɛ(a)" the ball centered at a with radius ɛ, or is it something else? Same goes for Vδ(a)

Comment: It means  x∈ R : |x-a| <ɛ

Answer (score 0):

1. With $ \gamma: =\min \{ \epsilon, \delta\}$ we have $V_{\epsilon}(a) \cap V_{\delta}(a)=V_{\gamma}(a)$.
2. $V_{\epsilon}(a) \subseteq V_{\epsilon}(a) \cup V_{\delta}(a)$
3. With $ \epsilon= \frac{|a-b|}{3}$ let $U=V_{\epsilon}(a)$ and $V=V_{\epsilon}(b)$